# Git rebase with no arguments changing commits IDs and order

Tags: git, rebase, branching-and-merging

I would like to understand why rebase is changing the order and the commits ID. Consider the following commit tree:

```
       F1 -- F2 feature
       /
M1 -- M2 -- M3 main
```

There is another team commiting changes to main and pushing to remote and I need to catch up latest changes from main to feature, so I decided to use rebase as following:

```
myrepo git:(main) git pull origin main
```

Now my local `main` branch contains the latest changes from remote (M3). Now I need to go to feature and do a git rebase:

```
➜  myrepo git:(main) git checkout feature
Switched to branch 'feature'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature'.

➜  myrepo git:(feature) git rebase main     
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature.
```

Checking my commits history:

```
d78c8d5 (HEAD -> feature) F3
775e06c F2
1cc4843 F1
31a5870 (origin/main, origin/HEAD, main) M3
9fd7263 M2
756c88d M1
eec81ba Initial commit
```

The result is expected since rebase put all feature commits "after" main commits. The question is, if I run rebase without any arguments as following:

```
➜  myrepo git:(feature) git rebase
warning: skipped previously applied commit 1cc4843
warning: skipped previously applied commit 775e06c
hint: use --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits
hint: Disable this message with "git config advice.skippedCherryPicks false"
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature.
```

Besides the warning messages saying it will skip previously applied commits, it really changed the order and commits ID:

```
65ed33d (HEAD -> feature) F3
2b7e517 M3
7cea741 (origin/feature) F2
9c267ef F1
9fd7263 M2
756c88d M1
eec81ba Initial commit
```

It seems something related to upstream, because now it is possible to run a push without the `--force` option.

```
➜  myrepo git:(feature) git push
Enumerating objects: 11, done.
Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Delta compression using up to 10 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 641 bytes | 641.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: 
remote: To create a merge request for feature, visit:
```

What exactly is this "second time rebase" without argument doing? Why is it changing commits?"

Comment: Plain `git rebase` is documented to use your current branch's configured base, here that's `origin/feature` as usual. So that's what it did, it rebased your checked-out history on the default `origin/feature`, and mentioned that some of the commits look like they were already cherrypicked there so it skipped them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each rebase operation will take whatever commits are not already present on the destination and recreate them there. I say recreate, and not move, because a commit is something immutable, with its fixed set of changes, parents, message and other meta-data. A rebase is creating a new commit with the same message, changes, meta-data but different parents.

Now I will add `origin/feature` to your original graph, pointing to F2 because that's where your final log says it is.

I will also add `F3` to your original graph, and assume `feature` pointed to it. The logs you show after the rebases are impossible unless that was the case. (Or did you create F3 after the first rebase? In any case, you're showing it in the results of the rebase, so it has to have gotten created either initially or before the second rebase, but origin/feature never pointed to it according to your last log output.)

Updated initial state:

```
              F3 feature
              /
       F1 -- F2 origin/feature
       /
M1 -- M2 -- M3 main, origin/main
```

The first rebase created F1', F2' and F3' and set `feature` to point to F3', but left `origin/feature` alone, still pointing at F2:

```
         F1 -- F2 origin/feature
         /
        /     F1' -- F2' -- F3' feature
       /     /
M1 -- M2 -- M3 main, origin/main
```

The second rebase says take `feature` and rebase it on top of `origin/feature`. That means take M3, F1', F2' and F3' and add them after F2. M2 is in the shared history, so it does not need to be considered. Now, by default that might create M1 - M2 - F1 - F2 - M3' - F1'' - F2'' - F3'' as the new history for `feature`, except that the rebase notices that F1' has the same change set as F1, so it skips it (as the log message says), and ditto for F2'. The final results you get are as expected once you skip creating F1'' and F2'':

```
                M3' -- F3'' -- feature
                /
         F1 -- F2 origin/feature
         /
        /     F1' -- F2' -- F3' (nothing points here anymore, but it still exists)
       /     /
M1 -- M2 -- M3 main, origin/main
```

(The original F3 also still exists, with F2 as its parent but no branch pointing to it. My graph is getting too crowded to display it, though.)

Now, if you had run your second rebase with `--keep-empty`, which tells the rebase to "Keep the commits that do not change anything from its parents in the result," you would have indeed had F1 - F2 - M3' - F1'' - F2'' - F3'', but F1'' and F2'' would have been empty commits, since they were trying to reproduce F1' and F2' which are bringing in changes that have already been applied earlier in the history leading to M3'.